# White screen appears after dismissing Admob interstitial ad

Tags: windows-phone-8, admob

I am having an issue with the interstitial ads where on dismissing the interstitial ads, a white screen appears for 2-3 seconds, which is non responsive, and only after 2-3 seconds, it disappears and the app becomes visible again.
Platform: WP8
SDK version: GoogleMobileAdsSdkWindowsPhone8-6.5.13
Code snippet is below (I have placed only the required stuff, apologies in advance if it proves to be difficult to work with)

```
    /*
C# implementation of the s3eAdMob extension.

Add win8-specific functionality here.

These functions are called via Shim class from native code.
*/
/*
 * NOTE: This file was originally written by the extension builder, but will not
 * be overwritten (unless --force is specified) and is intended to be modified.
 */
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows;
using System.Threading.Tasks;        

using GoogleAds;

namespace s3eAdMobManaged
{
    public  class s3eAdMobManaged
    {
        private string interstitialAdID = "ca-app-pub-3090050976150818/7861588484";
        private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

        public void initAdMob_managed()
        {
            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(interstitialAdID);
            interstitialAd.DismissingOverlay += OnInterstitialDismissingOverlay;

            AdRequest adRequestInterstitial = new AdRequest();
            adRequestInterstitial.ForceTesting = false;
            interstitialAd.LoadAd(adRequestInterstitial);
        }

        public void showAdMobInterstitial_managed()
        {
            interstitialAd.ShowAd();
        }

        private void OnInterstitialDismissingOverlay(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
        {
            loadInterstitialAdAsync();
        }

        private async void loadInterstitialAdAsync () {
            await Task.Run(() => loadInterstitialAd());
        }

        private void loadInterstitialAd()
        {
            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(interstitialAdID);
            interstitialAd.DismissingOverlay += OnInterstitialDismissingOverlay;
            AdRequest adRequestInterstitial = new AdRequest();
            adRequestInterstitial.ForceTesting = false;
            interstitialAd.LoadAd(adRequestInterstitial);
        }
    }
}
```

Description of the code:
initAdMob_managed: For initialization. Called by the app on startup. Loads the ad but does not show it.
showAdMobInterstitial_managed: For showing the already loaded ad.
OnInterstitialDismissingOverlay: Callback that gets executed on dismissing the ad. I am using this method to reload the ad data so that it will be available the next time it is to be shown, this task is carried out asynchronously since the data being loaded is not required right away. When need be, showAdMobInterstitial_managed will get called.

Initially, I thought that it could be OnInterstitialDismissingOverlay logic issue. So, I removed this method altogether (removing this method will cause issue in reloading the ad, but the first time execution should be without any issue). Even after the removal, there was no change.

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, different engine. You appear to be using marmalade?
If you look at the admob interstitial samples for WP8, you see that they have this white version too as soon as you close the ad.
It just doesn't show that long, as the context switch doesn't take so long.

The engine I am currently using also takes a while to switch back from the ad to the game.

I guess you have encountered the same problem?

My tip: test your game in release mode and without a debugger or console attached ... this speeded up the whole process and the white ad now only is visible for like 1 second compared to 4-5 ... maybe that helps.